# Извлечение чисел из строки

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

Есть текстовые данные следующего вида:

```
                "event_id": "1410",
                "event_id": "1409",
                "event_id": "1404",
```

Необходимо из каждой строки извлечь числа.

Comment: Весь код из вопроса можно удалить, потому что он не имеет отношения к проблеме. Вместо него лучше добавить вашу неудачную попытку с `replace`.

Answer (score 3):

```
import re

a = '"event_id": "1410"'
b = re.search(r'\d+',a).group(0)
print(b)
```

```
1410
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сразу скомпилировать регулярное выражение, если его планируется множественное переиспользование:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'\d+')

a = '"event_id": "1410"'
b = regex.search(a).group(0)
```